# How to run Apache Beam Python pipelines on Flink cluster in Kubernetes?

Tags: python, kubernetes, apache-beam

Attempting to run the [word count example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py) on minikube following the Flink Kubernetes instructions [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/ops/deployment/kubernetes.html#setup-kubernetes), but the job never completes. The Python Beam SDK worker pooler doesn't appear to do any work.

In addition to the instructions for configuring a Flink Kubernetes cluster, I added a Python SDK worker pool to the taskmanager deployment. If I understand correctly, the purpose of the worker pool is to execute the Python portions of the pipeline. See full k8s deployment.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flink-taskmanager
  namespace: flink-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flink
      component: taskmanager
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flink
        component: taskmanager
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: taskmanager
        image: flink:1.10.2-scala_2.11
        workingDir: /opt/flink
        command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "$FLINK_HOME/bin/taskmanager.sh start; \
          while :;
          do
            if [[ -f $(find log -name '*taskmanager*.log' -print -quit) ]];
              then tail -f -n +1 log/*taskmanager*.log;
            fi;
          done"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6122
          name: rpc
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 6122
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 60
        volumeMounts:
        - name: flink-config-volume
          mountPath: /opt/flink/conf/
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 9999  # refers to user _flink_ from official flink image, change if necessary
      - name: beam-worker-pool
        image: apache/beam_python3.7_sdk:2.24.0
        args: ["--worker_pool"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 50000
          name: pool
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 50000
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 60
        volumeMounts:
        - name: flink-config-volume
          mountPath: /opt/flink/conf/
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 9999
      volumes:
      - name: flink-config-volume
        configMap:
          name: flink-config
          items:
          - key: flink-conf.yaml
            path: flink-conf.yaml
          - key: log4j.properties
            path: log4j.properties
```

I am running the example as follows:

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount \
--output /tmp/results/count \
--runner FlinkRunner \
--flink_master=localhost:8081 \
--environment_type=EXTERNAL \
--environment_config=localhost:50000
```

I used the documentation at https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/sdk-harness-config/ to set the `environment_type` and `environment_config` values.

The job gets added to the job manager and I can view it in the Flink UI, but the job never completes. I started poking around the container logs as noticed the beam-worker-pool has the following logs:

```
Starting worker with command ['/opt/apache/beam/boot', '--id=1-1', '--logging_endpoint=localhost:46005', '--artifact_endpoint=localhost:43851', '--provision_endpoint=localhost:37079', '--control_endpoint=localhost:37961']
2020/09/28 16:44:00 Provision info:
pipeline_options:<fields: fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > > > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > fields: > > logging_endpoint: artifact_endpoint: control_endpoint: dependencies: 
2020/09/28 16:44:00 Initializing python harness: /opt/apache/beam/boot --id=1-1 --logging_endpoint=localhost:46005 --artifact_endpoint=localhost:43851 --provision_endpoint=localhost:37079 --control_endpoint=localhost:37961
2020/09/28 16:44:08 Failed to retrieve staged files: failed to retrieve /tmp/staged in 3 attempts: failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/staged/pickled_main_session
    caused by:
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = ; failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/staged/pickled_main_session
    caused by:
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = ; failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/staged/pickled_main_session
    caused by:
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = ; failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/staged/pickled_main_session
    caused by:
rpc error: code = Unknown desc =
```

Likewise the taskmanger is logging:

```
2020-09-28 16:46:00,155 INFO  org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ExternalEnvironmentFactory  - Still waiting for startup of environment from localhost:50000 for worker id 1-1
```

Not sure what I am missing. I checked the `/tmp/staging/pickled_main_session` on the worker pool and it is empty.

Note this issue is similar to these previous questions.
[How do I run Beam Python pipelines using Flink deployed on Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57851158/how-do-i-run-beam-python-pipelines-using-flink-deployed-on-kubernetes)
[Running Apache Beam python pipelines in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60411012/running-apache-beam-python-pipelines-in-kubernetes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default (as of this writing), Beam stages runtime dependencies ("artifacts") to a certain directory (/tmp/staged by default) that needs to be accessible to both the job server (in your case, the client) and the Beam worker.

You can get around this by setting the `--flink_submit_uber_jar` pipeline option. When `--flink_submit_uber_jar` is set, Beam wraps all your dependencies in a jar that is submitted to Flink.